# python logging question

Tags: python

I have a question about python standard logging mechanism. So if I use logging.config.fileConfig to load my configuration file, then I create loggers for some modules using logging.getLogger test them right after creation and they work. Now if I call logging.config.fileConfig again with the same configuration file and create loggers for some other module would the previos ones still work ? Basically for the following logic:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)
logger1 = logging.getLogger(module1)
logger2 = logging.getLogger(module2)
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)
logger3 = logging.getLogger(module3)
```

config_file is the same in both calls. Should logger1 and logger2 be functional ? How about if config_file is different in those calls? Currently my logger1 and logger2 are not working after i load a new config_file. So first step is to check if this is normal behaviour. If so is it possible to make this work without merging the two config_files into one big one?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config files are intended to completely replace the existing configuration with whatever is in the confguration - any loggers which are not named in the configuration, or children thereof, are disabled by `fileConfig()`, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig). you can prevent this disabling, but only on recent Python versions. It's not generally good practice to call `fileConfig()` multiple times in a program, unless you have a specific need to do so. It's not forbidden, but it's not usual.

A common usage involves configuring handlers on the root logger and perhaps one or two top-level loggers; does this apply to you?

Comment: Hey, the handlers are the same for all the defined loggers, but I do need a different qualname for each module. Passing a "disable_existing_loggers = False" got the result I wanted.